# R: How to extract values from contiguous raster cells that are not touched by SpatialLines?

Tags: r, geospatial, raster, r-raster, r-sp

I've been trying to extract values from a single attribute raster (area, in m2) that overlaps with lines (that is, a .shp SpatialLines).

The problem is that, along these lines, my raster sometimes goes from one to several contiguous cells in all directions.  Using the extract function only values from cells that are touched by the lines are extracted.  Thus, when I add up the extracted values from all lines a significant amount of area (m2) is lost due to cells that were not touched by the line and therefore values were not extracted.

I tried to work it around by:

Step 1 - first aggregating my raster to a lower resolution (i.e. increasing the fact argument) and then
Step 2 - rasterizing the lines using this aggregated raster (created in step 1) as a mold to make sure the rasterized lines would get thick enough to cover the horizontal spread of cells in my original resolution raster.
Step 3 - Then I resample the rasterized lines (created in step 2) back to the original resolution I started with.
Step 4 - Finally, extracted the values from the resampled rasterized lines (created in step 3).

However, it didn't quite work as now the total area (m2) varies according to the fact="" value I use when first aggregating the raster (in step 1).

I really appreciate if anyone has already dealt with a similar problem and can help me out here.  Here are the codes I've been running to try to get it to work:

```
# input raster file
g.025 <- raster("ras.asc")
g.1 <- aggregate(g.025, fact=2, fun=sum)

# input SpatialLines
Spline1 <- readOGR("/Users/xxxxx.shp")
Spline2 <- readOGR("/Users/xxxxx.shp")
Spline3 <- readOGR("/Users/xxxxx.shp")

# rasterizing using low resolution raster (aggregated)
c1 <- rasterize(Spline1, g.1, field=Spline1$type, fun=sum)
c2 <- rasterize(Spline2, g.1, field=Spline2$type, fun=sum)
c3 <- rasterize(Spline3, g.1, field=Spline3$type, fun=sum)

# resampling back to higher resolution
c1 <- resample(c1, g.025)
c2 <- resample(c2, g.025)
c3 <- resample(c3, g.025)

# preparing to extract area (m2) values from raster “g.025”
c1tab <- as.data.frame(c1, xy=T)
c2tab <- as.data.frame(c2, xy=T)
c3tab <- as.data.frame(c3, xy=T)
c1tab <- c1tab[which(is.na(c1tab$layer)!=T),]
c2tab <- c2tab[which(is.na(c2tab$layer)!=T),]
c3tab <- c3tab[which(is.na(c3tab$layer)!=T),]

# extracting area (m2) values from raster “g.025”
c1tab[,4] <- extract(g.025, c1tab[,1:2])
c2tab[,4] <- extract(g.025, c2tab[,1:2])
c3tab[,4] <- extract(g.025, c3tab[,1:2])
names(c1tab)[4] <- "area_m2"
names(c2tab)[4] <- "area_m2"
names(c3tab)[4] <- "area_m2"

# sum total area (m2)
c1_area <- sum(c1tab$area_m2)
c2_area <- sum(c2tab$area_m2)
c3_area <- sum(c3tab$area_m2)
tot_area <- sum(c1_area, c2_area, c3_area)
```

Thanks!

Andre

Comment: Perhaps you could find "touched" raster cells and see which of their neighbor meet your criterion.

Comment: Could you clarify a bit ? For example, I don't get what you mean with "The problem is that, along these lines, my raster sometimes goes from one to several contiguous cells in all directions." Also, it's not very clear to me what the expected result should be.